# How do you dynamically extract the last name from an excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to extract last name using mid function.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53571483/edit) to give us sample data, expected output what yo have tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function will return last name whatever you have in middle name or more word in middle.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

If you really need `MID()` function then you can go with.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", REPT(" ",100)),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))*100,100))
```

Comment: I am getting #value for finding middle name as there is no middle name in the name. I am writing this function =MID(I15,FIND(" ",I15)+1,FIND(" ",I15,FIND(" ",I15)+1)-FIND(" ",I15)) Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If there is no middle name then what you want to show? You can use `IFERROR()` function to hide errors.

Answer (score 1):

Say if in Your Cell A1 name is "Paramjit Singh"

you can give formula : `=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1, LEN(A1)-1)` to get Last Name extracted if your name is in "FirstName LastName" format.

Comment: what if the name cell contains middle name as well

Answer (score 0):

## RIGHT

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),"",IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1))))
```

---

If there is no space character it returns "". If there is one `SPACE` character it returns the **second** string (Last Name). If there are two `SPACE` characters it returns the **third** string (Last Name).

### MID

Play with it.

[image]

```
=A1
=FIND(" ",A1)
=C2+1 or =FIND(" ",A1)+1
=LEN(A1)
=C4-C2 or =LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)
=MID(C1,C3,C5)
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))




=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))



=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,LEN(A2))
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A2)),A2,MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A2)),"",MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))

=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),A1,MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))

=MID(A23,FIND(" ",A23)+1,LEN(A23)) or C23
=MID(C23,FIND(" ",C23)+1,LEN(C23))

=MID(MID(A23,FIND(" ",A23)+1,LEN(A23)),FIND(" ",MID(A23,FIND(" ",A23)+1,LEN(A23)))+1,LEN(A23))

=MID(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))+1,LEN(A1))



=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),A1,IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),MID(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))+1,LEN(A1))))


=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),"",IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))),"",FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))+1,LEN(A1))))
```

Comment: I need it to be sone using mid function.

Comment: @ParamjitS use the dame logic with find() and apply it to mid()